# merging two arrays in nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, express

This function will returns an array containing shop details and images.

```
function listshops(callback)
    {   
     var array=[3,4];
      async.each(array,function(dat,callback){

         async.parallel([

             function(callback){
                c    function listshops(callback)
    {   
     var array=[3,4];/*shopId*/
      async.each(array,function(dat,callback){

         async.parallel([

             function(callback){
                client.connection.query('select * from shop where shopId=?',dat,function(err,data1){
                callback(null,data1);

               });
            },       

             function (callback) {
                client.connection.query('select * from image where shopId=?',dat,function(err,data2){
                callback(null,data2);

               });
            }
         ],
         function(err,data)
         {
         console.log(data);

         });
     });

    }
```

The output for above code is:: https://i.stack.imgur.com/laxf8.png

I need to merge the array containing shop information and images into single array.That is shop information with corresponding images.

```
[
    { shopId: 3, shopName: '1', address: 'abc', contactNumber: 1234 },
    { imageId: 1, shopId: 3, imageUrl: 'aaa' },
    { imageId: 2, shopId: 3, imageUrl: 'bbb' } 
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flatten the array using reduce:
[[1],[2]] --> [1,2]

```
var array = [[1,2],[3]];
array.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return prev.concat(curr);
});
```

In your case:

```
  function listshops(callback)
    {   
     var array=[3,4];/*shopId*/
      async.each(array,function(dat,callback){

         async.parallel([

             function(callback){
                client.connection.query('select * from shop where shopId=?',dat,function(err,data1){
                callback(null,data1);

               });
            },       

             function (callback) {
                client.connection.query('select * from image where shopId=?',dat,function(err,data2){
                callback(null,data2);

               });
            }
         ],
         function(err,data)
         {
            var result = data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
              return prev.concat(curr);
            });
            console.log(result);
         });
     });

    }
```

Comment: The code you written works perfectly. But the problem here is:                                                            [ { shopId: 3, shopName: '1', address: 'abc', contactNumber: 1234 },
  { imageId: 1, shopId: 3, imageUrl: 'aaa' },
  { imageId: 2, shopId: 3, imageUrl: 'bbb' } ]
[ { shopId: 4, shopName: '2', address: 'bbb', contactNumber: 1234 },
  { imageId: 3, shopId: 4, imageUrl: 'ccc' },
  { imageId: 4, shopId: 4, imageUrl: 'ddd' } ]                                                               From this array how to fecth data having  shopId=3 only.

Comment: when i give result[0] it fetches the two shop details. when i give result[1] it fetches the image id(1,3).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37695717/json-array-is-not-getting-in-expected-format: just check this question please.